# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function(…)

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, fullcalendar, laravel-blade

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        left:   'Calendar',
        center: '',
        right:  'today prev,next'
    })

});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
    </head>
  <body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

I am trying to add calendar with my blade template and I end up with this error.

> app.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function(…)

my head section looks like this

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
```

and than after that I am calling fullCalender on ready event

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

});
</script>
```

With CDN I am trying to fetch latest Jquery and FullCalendar.

With my snippet i have added /lib/moment.min.js I confirm that this file loads fine from my local machine.

Comment: Put your scripts at the bottom of your html instead of the head tag

Comment: @SamarRizvi I have already tried it. no luck so far.

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle to check

Comment: Did you try to download the javascript files? maybe there is a load error for the files?

Comment: It's so weird. I have just put the entire code in one .html file and put it on my desktop and ran it and it does popup the canlendar. I dont why it's not working when I tried to put it in my .blade template. which generates the same code as it's in my .html file.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions below? Can you attach your entire html file? Its probably something in the order of your file, because this error means that the fullCalendar plugin was not installed properly on the jquery you are using. Sometimes it means you have multiple jquery instances in your project...

Comment: Thanks @Kinnza. I have removed one of the .js file which resides at bottom of the page and it started working. you're right "Multiple jquery Instances"

Comment: how resolved? i have this problem!

Answer (score 3):

Where is your jquery ui and you need to run scripts at the bottom and css at top.

Codepen Demo http://codepen.io/norcaljohnny/pen/OWLjaX

```
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css' />
</head>

<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>

<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
</body>
```

This is the sample source from the developer.

```
> <meta charset='utf-8' /> <link href='../fullcalendar.min.css'
> rel='stylesheet' /> <link href='../fullcalendar.print.min.css'
> rel='stylesheet' media='print' /> <script
> src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script> <script
> src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script> <script
> src='../lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script> <script
> src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script> <script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include your script after including your jquery library

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
        </head>
      <body>
         <div id='calendar'></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // put your options and callbacks here
                left:   'Calendar',
                center: '',
                right:  'today prev,next'
                });

            });
        </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all for your time taking to help me out here.
I found that I have got other .js file resides at the bottom of the page which causes this issue. I commented out that .js and I got the calendar showing on my blade template.
Thanks all.

Comment: how ? in my template i have only a jquery but the error persist