# Initialize FullCalendar with JQuery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I installed FullCalendar with npm like this :

```
npm install jquery moment fullcalendar
```

I'm trying to initialize FullCalendar with JQuery  :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'fullcalendar';

jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ){

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
  });

});
```

When I execute the script, I get this error :

> jquery.js:4055 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a
> function

Comment: you need to connect plugins and css plugin - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414200/uncaught-typeerror-fullcalendar-is-not-a-function

Comment: fullCalendar isn't a jQuery plugin anymore. The last version which used jQuery was 3.x. the current version is 5.x. check the documentation for examples of how to initialise the calendar. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6 . Neither jQuery or momentJS is needed anymore. If you are studying examples online, make sure they are up to date.